# PHP Wamp server - 2 SSL certificates on one server

Tags: php, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, wampserver

I have  a PHP (Wamp) server that should host two different domains.

Each domain has a different certificate files (.crt .key)

I am trying to edit the ***httpd-ssl.conf*** file to configure each domain certificate.

However, I cannot define the correct filter in the virtual host header. Only this filter works:

**VirtualHost *default*:443**

Which basiclly means that all domain are directed to one default certificate (And I need each one to direct to a different certificate)

I want to configure it so each domain will use a different filter. Example:

**VirtualHost domain1.com:443**

**VirtualHost domain2.com:443**

But this does not work. When I configure it like this, neither of the domains get the certificate.

I am only trying to edit the ***httpd-ssl*** file, should I also edit other files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You need to create 2 virtual hosts with their two respective ServerName directives (ServerName domain1.com and ServerName domain2.com). Do not use , usually <VirtualHost *:443> is what you need. The VirtualHost directive determines on which IP address to listen, not the name. If you put a domain name inside  it's going to resolve it to an IP address on server startup, something you do not want for various reasons. See this answer on Serverfault for an example configuration.

https://serverfault.com/questions/744960/configuring-ssl-with-virtual-hosts-under-apache-and-centos/745285#745285